# using forward declarations instead of void* C++

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Is it possible to use a **forward declarations** instead of **void*** or the preference is to use **typedef** ?

I am using a Specific class in my API. for the clients who use it, the class is represented by `void*` so the clients would not need to use the header files.

Which of these choices is better?

```
class A;
class b
{
    A* simple;
};
```

or

```
typedef void* A;
class b
{
    A simple;
};
```

Comment: Those are three completely different things...

Comment: Use them where? C++ is not a "one approach fits all" kind of language.

Comment: I honestly don't know how they are related to each other.

Comment: @iBug: I think I know at least how two of these relate.

Comment: @Rakete1111: See my answer.

Comment: @nader Such cases are usually handled using interfaces in C++. You can make use of dynamic (virtual inheritance) or static polymorphism (templates). Even in C you usually don't use completely opaque structs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Actually I think it was pretty clear what he's asking (especially after the correction).

Comment: @einpoklum I believe my advice isn't that bad tho.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, yes, but you did cast a close vote. Remember OP is a newbie, I think we can cut him/her some slack - plus he's elaborated some more.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Dein Kommentar erinnert mich an: F: Wissen Sie, wie spät es ist? A: Ja - also nicht sehr sinnvoll.

Comment: @AlBundy Haha, English please :) I don't think your analogy is right though. It's like asking whether I should use a hammer, a computer or a rope. The three things have nothing in common.

Comment: **Be detailed:** i think after my edit, the problem is clear to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use something like:

```
class A;

class B {
    A* the_a;
}
```

instead of

```
class B {
    void* the_a;
}
```

in your C++ code, and the former is better code than the latter. However, don't be quick to use raw pointers unless you really need to.

Finally, I strongly recommend you avoid typedef'ing pointer types using names which do not clearly indicate the type is of a pointer, since that's confusing (and not useful).

Comment: @nader: Yes, that's very wrong, since A is not a pointer. And this typedef will be extremely confusing. Also, while I figured out what you were asking, it wasn't very clear, which is why you got all the downvotes.

Comment: @nader I wouldn't take any windows header files as the ultimate source of wisdom what to do best with advanced c++ (linux system headers neither BTW). These are mostly C-API definitions.

Comment: @nader: That tells you something about the code quality of Windows then...

Comment: @einpoklum That's at least partially a myth. It's a C OS API. There are many things thoughtfully done, just to fulfill their needs for backwards compatibility aso.